# python mechanize - cannot submit login form

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am using mechanize (http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to login to www.coinotron.com, but the execution hangs when I do `br.submit()`

```
import mechanize  
...  
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open("https://coinotron.com/app?action=logon")
form = br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form["name"] = "myusername"
br.form["password"] = "mypassword"
reponse = br.submit() # HERE THE EXECUTION HANGS!
```

If I comment the password line then the scripts executes ok, but of course it does not login.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround, although I don't completely understand why it works. But it think br.submit() was sleeping due to HTTPRefreshProcessor.honor_time = True and HTTPRefreshProcessor.max_time having a big value.
So I added following line just after `br = mechanize.Browser()`:

```
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1, honor_time=True)
```

Following pages helped me out, although not directly related to my problem:
[Mechanize in Python - Redirect is not working after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11732792/mechanize-in-python-redirect-is-not-working-after-submit)

http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/hints.html